# How to discard or clear MatDailog data after close or after submit

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an component called `customers(dialog window)`,Inside this there are 2 components called **list** and **display**, From the **list** component i will push some object to the **table** present in the **display** component like this:

[image]

COMPONENTS CODE:

**list.component.html**

```
<h3>List</h3>
<form [formGroup]="addListForm">
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select  formControlName="CustomerIds" placeholder="Select Customer" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let customer of customers" [value]="customer" >
      {{customer.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<br>
<button  (click)="onAdd()">Add</button>
</form>
```

**list.component.ts**

```
import {Component,  OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder,FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { ContactService } from '../contacts.service';
import { MatOptionSelectionChange } from '@angular/material';
import { ICustomer } from '../models';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
public customers: ICustomer;
public someCustomer: ICustomer;
public addListForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
  private myService: ContactService,
   public dataService: DataService) { }

  public async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.addListForm = this.fb.group({
      CustomerIds: [null],
    });
    this.customers = await this.myService.getCustomers('');
  }
  public async selected(event: MatOptionSelectionChange, customer: ICustomer): Promise<void> {
    this.myService.onCustomerSelect.next(customer);
  }

    public onAdd(): void {
    this.someCustomer = this.addListForm.value;
    this.dataService.onSelectCustomer.next(this.someCustomer);
  }

}
```

**display.component.html**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="selectedCustomers?.CustomerIds" >
            .....
  </table>
```

**display.component.ts**

```
import {Component,  OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder,FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { ICustomer } from '../models';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-display',
  templateUrl: './display.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./display.component.css']
})
export class DisplayComponent implements OnInit {
public  contacts: ICustomer;
public selectedCustomers: any;
public displayForm: FormGroup;
public addCustomer: any;

public displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'button'];

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,public dataService: DataService) { }

  public async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.displayForm = this.fb.group({
    });
   this.dataService.onSelectCustomer.subscribe(value => {
   this.selectedCustomers = value;
  });
  }

}
```

Now, I  will  push some objects(customers) from **list** component to **display** component and i will close dialog window.If i open the dialog window again the table data must be cleared without any any previously pushed data from **list** component.How can i clear the table cache?

**[Stackblitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-csxs3s?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main file `app.component.ts` use MatDialog's `afterClosed()` method which is getting called every time when the Dialog is closed to empty the old data of the table.

```
public openAdd(): void {
  const dialogRef: MatDialogRef<CustomersComponent> = this.dialog.open(CustomersComponent, {
    width: '80vw', height: '80vh',
  });
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    this.dataService.onSelectCustomer.next([]); 
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not an issue regarding cache as you think. You are using Service to share the data among the components so the existing pushed value into the `next()` that values or data is still available to use. You can read more about [`Services`](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4).

So if you want to clear the existing data then there are two ways:

> Solution 1:

As stated by FarhatZaman you can subscribe to the dialogRef.afterClosed() method:

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(res => {
      this.dataService.onSelectCustomer.next([]);
 })
```

> Solution 2:

You can clear the data in the method as like:

```
public onSave(): void {
   this.addCustomer = this.selectedCustomers;
   this.dataService.onSelectCustomer.next([]); // Here
}
```

[`Stackblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-rf7ez2)

Comment: Sorry i gave the old working DEMO, In the new working demo ==> **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-rr7rnq?file=src/app/display/display.component.ts**,  clearing  `table` data after closing dialog window is working fine, but again i am unable add it to `table`.

Comment: Please consider this link ===> **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-rr7rnq?file=src/app/display/display.component.ts** @Prashanth Pimpale

Comment: @Prashanth Have fixed with error here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-unmafj

Comment: I tried with `else condition` but i forgot to check `value.CustomerIds`, Anyhow i got the expected  result,Thanks for your response.